# How to consume data from two std::ranges at a time (emulating std::views::zip in C++20)?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

I'm working with C++20 and have a scenario where I have two ranges, A and B, and I want to consume an element from each an use it to construct an object.

Having thought `std::views::zip` was available, I wrote:

```
namespace views = std::views;

std::vector<int> a0{1,2,3,4};
std::vector<int> b0{6,7,8,9};

a = a0 | views::transform(foo); // where foo and bar are some functions
b = b0 | views::transform(bar); 

auto objects = views::zip(a,b)
  |  views::transform([](auto&& pair){ return Object{pair.first, pair.second}; });
```

And was the informed by the compiler that `views::zip()` is not available until C++23!

So, my question is: **is a convenient way as it stands to emulate this behaviour**?

I thought you might be able to write something like...

```
namespace ranges = std::ranges

auto objects = ranges::iota_view{1, 10}
  | views::transform([&a, &b](int i){ return Object(std::get<i>(a), std::get<i>(b)); });
```

but I suspect that since `i` isn't a compile time parameter then it can't be used in `std::get<>()`. Therefore, I ask if anyone has a more elegant solution?

Comment: "*is a convenient way as it stands to emulate this behaviour?*" If there was, you wouldn't need `zip_view`. Also, why are you trying to use `get` instead of `[i]`?

Comment: I'm somewhat unfamiliar with ranges, I thought they did not have operator[]

Comment: @JonahF They do (if they can).

Comment: @Barry Ok, it seems as though a range which has been derived from a views::transform does not have operator [] (maybe?!). cppreference says ranges::transform_view does but when I try it in my code I get an error.

Comment: @JonahF: The range doesn't have `[]`; random_access *iterators* do.

Comment: @NicolBolas [Yes, the range does too](https://godbolt.org/z/fvTczza74).

Comment: @NicolBolas Right, so https://godbolt.org/z/W6G6z6G58 doesnt because im trying to index into the range, and not a random_access iterator on the range? And in that case, how can I access elements of the transformed result?

Comment: @NicolBolas That example was helpful thanks. I can see my problem now - in my actual code I was performing a views::filter then a views::transform. Its the ranges::filter_view which does not have operator[]. That's annoying. (https://godbolt.org/z/bY6bxd1WP)